Vite-electron doesnt build properly
I've been facing the problem of not being able to make a working electron build for a few days now. When trying to build using electron-builder build --win --x64, I get the return of the dist directory, where everything looks right in the app.asar file. But when I try to run the electron executable, it only runs in the background processes, without rendering any screen.
Any ideas what it could be, or how I could further investigate the error?
Additionally, when I try to run "start-electron": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:8000 && electron ."
the program fails returning the following error:
Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
Even though the vite.config.js file is configured correctly:
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: './index.html'  // Definindo o ponto de entrada como index.html na raiz
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 8000
  },

To solve this, I already tried to create an electron-builder.js file, and made changes to my json package. I thought about using vite-electron to solve the problem, but I haven't tried this solution yet as it requires other configuration files.
electron-builder
"files": [
    "package.json",
    "public/**/*",
    "electron/**/*"
  ],
  "win": {
    "target": [
      {
        "target": "nsis",
        "arch": ["x64"]
      }
    ]
  },

package-json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "set BROWSER=none && set NODE_ENV=development && npm run dev",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "electron-builder build --win --x64",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && cross-env IS_DEV=true electron .",
    "electron:pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "electron:dev": "electron .",
    "electron:builder": "electron-builder build --win --x64",
    "build:for:electron": "cross-env ELECTRON=true vite build",
    "app:build": "npm run build:for:electron && npm run electron:builder",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "electron-start": "cross-env IS_PROD=true concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run dev\" \"npm run electron\"",
    "start-electron": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:8000 && electron .",
    "package": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js --publish never",
    "publish": "electron-builder build --win --publish always"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.19",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.9.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^6.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "wait-on": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "electron": "^30.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^24.13.3",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.5.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.11",
    "vite-plugin-copy": "^0.1.6"
  },
"files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "electron/**/*"

